# Using c#, How can I take benefit of using nullable valuetypes when I have a variable of object type?

Tags: c#, object, types

Using c#, How can  I take benefit of using nullable value types when I have a variable of object type?

For example, I have a method Insert within a class which takes 4 arguments:

```
public int Update(Int32 serial, object deliveryDate, object quantity, object shiftTime)
{
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

As you can guess, this method inserts a new record in a table. The table (Table1), has 4 colums: Serial int, DeliveryDate DateTime null, Quantity float  not null and ShiftTime smallint null

Now, my quastion is : how can I take benefit of using nullable valuetypes and also ho can I convert object to my desirable types like DateTime?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are your parameters of type object in the first place? Why isn't it:

```
public int Update(int serial, DateTime? deliveryDate,
                  double? quantity, short? shiftTime)
```

(Note that `decimal` may be a better choice than `double` - something to think about.)

If you can possibly change your method signature, that's probably the way to go.

Otherwise, what are you really asking in your question? If you *can't* change the parameters, but the arguments should be of type `DateTime` (or null), `double` (or null) and `short` (or null) then you can just cast them to their nullable equivalents. That will unbox `null` to the null value of the type, and non-null values to corresponding non-null values:

```
object x = 10;
int? y = (int?) x; // y = non-null value 10
x = null;
y = (int?) x; // y is null value of the Nullable<int> type
```

EDIT: To respond to the comment...

Suppose you have a text box for the shift time. There are three options: it's filled in but inappropriately (e.g. "foo"), it's empty, or it's valid. You'd do something like this:

```
short? shiftTime = null;
string userInput = shiftTimeInput.Text;
if (userInput.Length > 0) // User has put *something* in
{
    short value;
    if (short.TryParse(userInput, out value))
    {
        shiftTime = value;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do whatever you need to in order to handle invalid
        // input.
    }
}
// Now shiftTime is either null if the user left it blank, or the right value
// Call the Update method passing in shiftTime.
```

Comment: Jon, In GUI, I have a web form which gets 4 values from user.
For example, the form has a textbox for ShiftTime. 
but ShiftTime is not a mandatory form field. So It's possible the user doesn't enter any value for it. In this case , I should pass Null to ShiftTime column in Table1. how can I handle this one?

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [System.Nullable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type. It has some shortcuts in C#:

```
public int Update(
    int serial, 
    DateTime? deliveryDate, 
    float? quantity, 
    short? shiftTime)
```

Which allows you to call method like this:

```
Update(10, null, null, null);
```